# Stored the values in list and then sorting them using Collections is not working

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

Am trying to store the string values in a list using the variable 'optionsList'. But it's throwing NullPointer exception.Can some one please help me in resolving this.

Below is the code:

public static void CheckOptionsPresent(String s1) throws Exception
      {
               try{

```
           List optionsList = null;

           webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance button")));

           webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance button")).click();

           List<WebElement> list = webDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li"));

           int listcount = list.size();           
           System.out.println(listcount);
           String options[]=new String[listcount];


           for (int i=3; i<=listcount; i++ )
           {

           options[i-3] = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li:nth-child("+i+") a span")).getText();
           System.out.println(options[i-3]);
                   webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li:nth-child("+i+") a span")));

           optionsList = Arrays.asList(options);

           }

           System.out.println(optionsList);

           optionsList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));


           Collections.sort(optionsList);


           System.out.println("Sorted List:" + optionsList);
```

}

Comment: Can you show the output of your code?

Comment: Output :                                                                                              14
BC - British Columbia
MB - Manitoba
NB - New Brunswick
NL - Newfoundland and Labrador
NS - Nova Scotia
NT - Northwest Territories
NU - Nunavut
ON - Ontario
PE - Prince Edward Island
QC - Québec
SK - Saskatchewan
YT - Yukon Territory
[BC - British Columbia, MB - Manitoba, NB - New Brunswick, NL - Newfoundland and Labrador, NS - Nova Scotia, NT - Northwest Territories, NU - Nunavut, ON - Ontario, PE - Prince Edward Island, QC - Québec, SK - Saskatchewan, YT - Yukon Territory, null, null]
null

Comment: Vivek, thanks for the reply. But am new to Java not sure how to implement your suggestion,

Comment: Why is it not working? Your output is sorted. 14 BC..., MB..., NB....., YT...

Comment: for (int i=3; i<=listcount; i++ )
           {
           options[i-3] = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li:nth-child("+i+") a span")).getText();
           System.out.println(options[i-3]);
                   webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("article.ContactInfo.active div.half-left.contactInfo div.idProvinceOfIssuance div ul li:nth-child("+i+") a span")));

           optionsList = Arrays.asList(options);
           }

           System.out.println(optionsList);

Comment: here, optionsList is the output which is coming in sorted order from the dropdown value.  I need to sort them again to make it a generic function.

Comment: Nathan, Is it clear? Can you help me now?

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of String.You should use `Collections.sort(optionsList,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`

Comment: Sainik thanks for reply but still the output is same.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a simplified version of yours above, the below works fine.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        List optionsList = null;
        String options[] = new String[3];// listcount];
        options[0] = "cat";
        options[1] = "dog";
        options[2] = "alpha";
        optionsList = Arrays.asList(options);
        System.out.println(optionsList);
        optionsList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        Collections.sort(optionsList);
        System.out.println("Sorted List:" + optionsList);

    }
```

I think the issue is in the way you are reading values for options[].

try narrowing down the issue I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks alot Syed :) It worked for me.Your answer is really helpful.

Comment: Syed, Am unable to vote your answer. It says " Once you earn a total of 15 reputation then your votes will change the publicly  displayed post score".

Comment: cool, no problem :) I think you can mark it as answer though.